# Recyclerview mas Glide Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-glide, glide

Tengo un Recyclerview  donde atraves de la libreria GLIDE intento crear una lista de Thumbail de un video,algo asi deseo tener:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero no se muestra nada en el recyclerview:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Notas:

1)La libreria Glide ya la probe sin Reyclerview y funciono a la perfecccion.
2)Comprobe que la App si reconoce el video, que si existe.
3)Tenia una duda Glide me pide un Contexto como parametro, no se si es el contexto del MainActivity o del Adapter

Adjunto Codigo.

Activity Main XML :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/RecyclerId"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="508dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="1dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="1dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="152dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.494"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
```

Main Activity Java:

```
package com.example.recyclerview;
```

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.media.ThumbnailUtils;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
ArrayList<String> listDatos;
RecyclerView recycler;
ImageView mi_imagen;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



    recycler=(RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.RecyclerId);
    recycler.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this,LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL,false));
    listDatos= new ArrayList<String>();

    for (int i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        listDatos.add("Ejemplo: " + i);
    }
    Context contexto = this.getApplicationContext();

    AdapterDatos adapter=new AdapterDatos(listDatos,contexto);
    recycler.setAdapter(adapter);

}
```

}

Adapatador:

```
package com.example.recyclerview;
```

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.VideoView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class AdapterDatos extends RecyclerView.Adapter {

```
public Context mContext;
ArrayList<String> listDatos;


public AdapterDatos(ArrayList<String> listDatos,Context context)
{

    this.listDatos = listDatos;
    mContext=context;
}



@NonNull
@Override
public ViewHolderDatos onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view= LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_list,parent,false);
    return new ViewHolderDatos(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolderDatos holder, int position) {
   holder.asignarDatos(listDatos.get(position));
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {

    return listDatos.size();
}

public class ViewHolderDatos extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {


    ImageView imagen;




    public ViewHolderDatos(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        imagen=(ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.ImagenP);
    }

    public void asignarDatos(String s) {

        String filePath = "/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/video.mp4";

        Glide.with(mContext).load(filePath).error(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background).into(imagen);



    }
}
```

}

Item:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imagen_dato"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:layout_margin="0dp"
    android:contentDescription="@string/todo" />
```

Comment: te marca algún error el Logcat?

Comment: Ningun tipo de error.

Comment: Hola, puedes agregar el archivo R.layout.item_list. :)

Comment: Ya agregue el Itemlist

Answer (score 0):

Me parece que tu viewholder, estas cargando en una imageView que no existe.

```
imagen=(ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.ImagenP);
```

la variable `image` tiene la referencia para el id `R.id.ImagenP` pero en tu xml del item tienes como id `imagen_dato`, podrías intentar la siguiente modificación.

```
imagen=(ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.image_dato);
```